# 7zip logging & left-over .tmp files

Tags: logging, batch-file, compression

I have a batch file that runs nightly to compress some PST's, it uses 7zip & generally is pretty successful.

However it tends to **create left-over .tmp files (9 over 2 days), I want to delete these.** According to multiple 7zip forums, patch requests, & other websites I can change the directory it stores those, but nothing more. **I speculate this shouldn't be happening & something is wrong, furthermore occasionally it has skipped files. I want to keep a log**, even if everything is fine, its a good fall back if something goes funky.

My batch file has a separate line/command for each PST: `7z.exe u -t7z JENNIFER.7z JENNIFER.PST -r`. I have successfully gotten a log when I append " `>7zip.log`". However when I do that for two different lines/commands only the last one is logged, thus I assume its being overwritten.

Short of making one long complex command *(as I have PST over 2GB's among other files in that folder that I don't want compressed)*; does anyone have any other ideas/thoughts

Side note: Now that I think about it my backup agent might be interrupting access to .7z files, thus causing all this. However oddly enough the batch file is a 'windows scheduled task' & it ran with result 0x0 (which if I remember right is success) & backup was also successful. Either way I'd like to learn how to properly log with 7zip & feedback on why .tmp files may be left over from a compression command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most backup program does not lock file. Antivirus may lock the file for checking and keep it from being delete. So you can disable anti virus first.

Answer (score 2):

Use ">>7zip.log" instead of ">7zip.log", this will make the output to be appended to the text file, and not overwrite the previous one.

Comment: This answer isn't very useful -- given that Gregg has already mentioned that he was appending to file in his own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing [redirections](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true) wrong (found [some additional info](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true)). Issue hasn't happened in awhile, but now that I am redirecting err & stdout & appending to a file, I get all info I need to probably troubleshoot. I am considering this a one-off & closing